# Finding values NOT IN a GROUP BY in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to:

```
id    user_id    value
----------------------------
1     2          colour
2     2          receive_email
3     3          colour
4     3          receive_email
5     3          receive_info
```

I group this table by user_id. What I want to do is only return groups that do not contain the value 'receive_info'. So in the case above, I would be returned one row with he user_id = 2.

I have tried a few things, this being the latest:

```
SELECT id, user_id, value  
FROM table 
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING value NOT IN('receive_info');
```

I have also tried:

```
SELECT id, user_id, value  
FROM table 
WHERE value NOT IN('receive_info') 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

When I do this, I am getting the records back for users which do contain a value = 'receive'.

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT user_id
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    tableName b
            WHERE   a.user_id = b.user_id AND
                    value = 'receive_info'
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84bf1/2)

OR by using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.user_id
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN tableName b
            ON  a.user_id = b.user_id AND
                b.value = 'receive_info'
WHERE   b.user_id IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84bf1/5)

the two query will OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╗
║ USER_ID ║
╠═════════╣
║       2 ║
╚═════════╝
```